# All Links With Parameters not showing with a MySQLI Query

Tags: php, mysqli

My query with mysqli is only displaying 1 link whereas the original mysql query displayed all 6; any idea why this would happen?
I have two parameters stated in my query on displaying a link. One is the enabled value has to equal 1; the second is that the permissions value is equal to or less than 3 for the admin page.This is my old query that ran into no problems on my admin page:
Old Mysql Query

```
 <?php  
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM navigation WHERE enabled='1' AND permission<='3'");
                while ($row=
                mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo $row['link'];
                    echo '</li>';
                    }

        ?>
```

It displayed all the links that matched the variables.
My new Mysqli Query:

```
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}   
$query = 'SELECT * FROM navigation where enabled="1"';
$result = $db->query($query);
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
while ($row = $result->fetch_object());
{
    echo '<li>';
                echo $row->link;
                echo '</li>';
            }
?>
```

This query displays only the first link.

Comment: I don't see a loop anywhere. How do you expect it to show more than one result? Change `$row = $result->fetch_object()` to `while ($row = $result->fetch_object())`

Comment: Never used a loop in the mysql query; I blindly believed that it would be the same for mysqli. I've completely overlooked that and just always been doing a while without really thinking on why. On a second note. I added the while to mysqli and now it displays none of the content past the navigation and shows no navigation pane.

Comment: The loop is right there: `while ($row ...`

Comment: Remove this semicolon here: `while ($row = $result->fetch_object()); // there should be no semicolon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is kind of an answer. It resolves my first issue and gives me a new one.

```
  <?php
$server = "****";
    $user = "****";
    $pass = "*****";
    $webdb = "****";
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}   
$query = 'SELECT * FROM navigation where enabled="1"';
$result = $db->query($query);
$total_results = $result->num_rows;
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    echo '<li>';
                echo $row->link;
                echo '</li>';
                }

                            $result->free();

?>
```

Is the code that has displayed all the links that are set to enabled. My <=3 variable displays no links if added to the query and the rest of the web page is not being displayed now. I'll update as I find more information.